# How to invoke getSharedPreferences outside the onCreate function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

### Context

---

I'm currently building an app that allow people to create a "What To Do" list and checked the completed item in the list by tapping on that item.

This is the function that will be called when the button is clicked:

```
fun onClickButton(button: Button) {
    var sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(packageName + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPref.getString("store_list", "NO_LIST")
    // ...
}
```

And this is a snippet of the full code (MainActivity.kt)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun onClickButton(button: Button) {
        var sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(packageName + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val list sharedPref.getString("store_list", "NO_LIST")
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

### Problem

---

When I click one of the item, the app crashed and the log returned an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

### Solution I've tried

---

I've tried putting the `sharedPref` outside the function and in the `MainActivity` class as a null variable, then declaring the varible inside the `onCreate` function, like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var sharedPref: SharedPreferences? = null
    fun onClickButton(button: Button) {
        var sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(packageName + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val list = sharedPref?.getString("store_lock_app", "NO_CONFIG")
        if (list != null) {
            Log.d("list", list)
        }
        // ...
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(packageName + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

And when I click the item, the `list` output return null:

```
D/list: null
```

### Conclusion

---

So, is there any way to invoke getSharedPreferences outside the onCreate function?
(Also, all of this is inside the same Activity)

Comment: An activity cannot call a method like this on a different activity. There is nothing wrong with getting SharedPrefs in onClick, your problem is probably how you are calling it. Add that to the question.